# How can hide Textblock if observablecollection is null

Tags: xaml

Is it possible to hide TextBlock if binding observablecollection contain empty,using xaml codes.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xaml

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Labour,Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource ZeroToVisibilityConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="There is no data on this date" Margin="314,200,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="188"/>
```

Converter

```
public class ZeroToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return int.Parse(value.ToString()) == 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```